# I tried to wrap column with Singlechildscrollview Flutter but screen goes blank

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

[enter image description here][1]
Inside My column, there is a stack, a carousel slider,a gridview builder. I want to scroll all of them together. I tried to use singlechildscrollview as you can see in the code below. Please Someone help me how can I scroll those things together.

[1]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYexC.png`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYexC.png%60) enter code here`

Scaffold(
backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
// Color(0xFFFFF176),

```
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            children: [
              CarouselSlider(
                items: slideImage
                    .map((image) =>
                        Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
                          return Container(
                            height: 200,
                            width: 500,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
                              image: DecorationImage(
                                  image: AssetImage(image),
                                  fit: BoxFit.fill),
                            ),
                          );
                        }))
                    .toList(),
                options: CarouselOptions(
                  onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
                    setState(() {
                      activeIndex = index;
                    });
                  },
                  height: 300,
                  viewportFraction: 1,
                  autoPlay: true,
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: AnimatedSmoothIndicator(
                    activeIndex: activeIndex, count: slideImage.length),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 10,
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: GridView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            // physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            itemCount: menuImage.length,
            gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisCount: 2,
              childAspectRatio: 0.8,
              crossAxisSpacing: 8,
              mainAxisSpacing: 8,
            ),
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => Card(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
              ),
              color: Color(0xFFFFFDE7),
              elevation: 10,
              child: GridTile(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Image.asset(
                      menuImage[index],
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      title[index],
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

}
}

Answer (score 2):

If it takes too much height. so give height to the column.

like this..

```
 SingleChildScrollView(
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 500,
              child: Column(
                children: const [...],
              ),
            ),
          )
```

Answer (score 2):

In flutter, `Column` will take height as much as it can, `SingleChildScrollView` child dont have height (infinite). Combine together, Flutter don't know how to render them correctly and causing error.

To solve it, try to determine the height of `Column` by widgget like `SizedBox` or determine the `mainSize.min`.

Another way to solve it is wrap `Column` by `IntrinsicHeight` but not recommend cause it heavy.

Answer (score 1):

your expanded widget is taking whole space of column try removing it or replacing it with Sizedbox.

Answer (score 1):

I just experienced the same problem, because my `SingleChildScrollView` contains a `Column`, which contains a `Spacer`.

Removing the `Spacer` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It would be best if you gave height to the column you are using singlechildeScrollview.
Wrap column widget in **container** or **sizedbox** widget and give it height.
column widget has children widget GridView.builder that is wrapped in expanded so gridview.builder will try to take all available height in the column which will be infinite because it's not defined and you will get column covering screen taking infinite screen height in short blank screen.